# Two or more foreign key in the table

Tags: mysql, database

In MySQL I have these 3 tables  :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Seasons
(
 season_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 start_date DATE,
 end_date DATE,
 club_num INT,
 desc TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY(season_id)
);

ALTER TABLE Seasons AUTO_INCREMENT=10000;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Clubs
(
 club_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 club_name VARCHAR(70),
 PRIMARY KEY(club_id)
);

ALTER TABLE Clubs AUTO_INCREMENT=100000;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ClubsCloths
(
 season_id INT NOT NULL,
 club_id INT NOT NULL,
 first_shirt VARCHAR(50),
 second_shirt VARCHAR(50),
 PRIMARY KEY(season_id,club_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (season_id) REFERENCES Seasons(season_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (club_id) REFERENCES Clubs(club_id)
);
```

In the last one I have 2 foreign keys that reference to first and second table. Now I want to know is it wisely to have 2 foreign key in a one table ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal. The `ClubsCloths` table is used to support many-to-many relationship between `Seasons` and `Clubs`.

Comment: Does it have a problem if I have a 3 or more foreign keys in a table ?

Comment: You can create as many foreign keys as you need. Of course there is a limit; but I think that in this case, you should think about the database design and follow the rules of normalization - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal to have several foreign keys to different tables (or the same table, doesn't matter).